# Android WebView__Use HTML5 video tag conflict with transparent background?

Tags: android, video, webview

I am trying to make a Browser on Android and it extends WebView class.

**There are two functions of my Browser:**

**1.Could play html5 video tag.**
(I enable HardwareAccelerate and setWebChromeClient and it works fine on Android 4.0.)

**2.The Browser must have a transparent Background.**
(On Android 4.0, just setBackground(0) is not enough. I must also use setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null).)

But when I use setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null), the video tag can not paly. And that means setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) disable HardwareAccerlarate so the video tag can not work.

So Can I consider that On Android 4.0, the two function is conflicting?Is there any workaround?

```
//set BackGroundColor
setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11){
    setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

//set WebChromeClient
setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that, seems no guys met this issue as me.
So I think the two functions mentioned in my question is really conflicting.